# Can s process communicate on two different type of sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Can a process behave as server and listen on to two different type of sockets(TCP unix socket and TCP AF_INET socket) and also can a process behave as client and open two different type of sockets(TCP unix socket and TCP AF_INET socket) and connect to a server with respective type of sockets.

I have two processes one as a server and one as a client, running on same machine. Sockets are of type Unix stream socket. Now I want my server and client processes to open a new pair of TCP AF_INET socket and communicate over new pair of sockets as well while keeping communication on previous (Unix socket) intact.

For this at server I'll start a new thread for TCP AF_INET server socket. And at client also I'll start a new thread for TCP AF_INET client socket. Is it possible to have such a system. I'll write a c code for this on linux OS.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and quite common. Just give it a try ... And if you run into specific issues, we can help.

Comment: An example is the MySQL server. It uses a Unix domain socket for local clients, and a TCP socket for network clients. X Server also works like this.

Comment: You can use the unix tool `socat` to easily create proxies between network sockets, pipes, process stdin/stdout, tls and many more

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The Server may (should) use select function to monitor a set of sockets; The sockets may be of different types. The server then blocks on the select() call, wakes up on any readable data available on at east one socket.

The client process may use multiple threads, each thread has its own socket to communicate with the server. The client may also work with all sockets within the same execution context (thread), but this depends on the nature of the tasks the client should perform. In other words, this requires SW design and architecture.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response.  I understand fd returned by socket is just an int which we add in read set using FD_SET(). Just wondering can select monitor on two different type of sockets. I have one UNIX STREAM socket and another I want AF_INET stream socket. Though, man page of select do not says anything against it but it doesn't say anything to overrule my doubt.